# Jquery change selectbox value based on radio button value (or other way round)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a site that allows users to "guess / predict" the result of a sports match

To give you an idea what I am trying to achieve have a look at the following image:

[image]

The selected teams gets displayed at the bottom of the page along with their scores (as you can see on the bottom circle of the image)

**What Im trying to do**

1. As you can see in 1st circle the **selected score is 0** (zero) thus I would like the **radio button selected to automatically jump to draw**
2. In the second circle the user selected **draw by 12 points**, in that case I would like the **selectbox value to automatically default to zero** or disp appropriate message

**My Problem**

*My Script below **displays the selected team and selected score inside a div*** at the bottom of page

I can get the above described problem to work but that in turn affects the primary working of my script, explained above

Any idea how I can solve above problem without affecting the primary working of my script explained above.

**Please play around with my code snippet to get an idea of my problem**

**My Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$(':radio, select').change(function (e) {
    //clear the div
    $('#dispPicks').html('');
    //update the div
    $(':radio:checked').each(function (ind, ele) {
        var selectBoxVal = $(this).closest('div.team').find('select').val();
        selectBoxVal = selectBoxVal!=''? "By "+selectBoxVal:selectBoxVal;
        $('#dispPicks').append($(ele).val() +"  "+selectBoxVal+ '<br/>');
    });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team">
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Shaks" />
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Hurricanes" />
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Draw" />

<select>
        <option value="">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<br/>
</div>
<div class="team">
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="Crusaders" />
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="Pioneers" />
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="Draw" />
<select>
        <option value="">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<br/>
</div>
<div class="team">
<input type="radio" name="wow" value="Chelsea" />
<input type="radio" name="wow" value="Liverpool" />
<input type="radio" name="wow" value="Draw" />
<select>
        <option value="">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="dispPicks"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example seems to work as you requested.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 //Monitor change of team/draw
 $(':radio').change(function (e) {
  var selectBox = $(this).siblings("select");
  if($(this).val() == "Draw" && selectBox.val() !== ''){
   selectBox.val('');
  }
  updateDiv();
 });
 
 //Monitor change of select
 $('select').change(function (e) {
  
  var theRadios = $(this).siblings(":radio");
  
  //Check for draw condition
  if($(this).val() == '' ){
   //Change team/draw radios to draw
   theRadios.filter(':input[value="Draw"]').prop('checked', true);
  
  //Select indicates it is not a draw, clear draw status
  }else if(theRadios.filter(':checked').val() == "Draw"){
   theRadios.prop('checked', false);
  }
  updateDiv();
 });
});

/*
* (re)draw the div HTML
*/
function updateDiv(){
 //clear the div
 $('#dispPicks').html('');
 //update the div
 $(':radio:checked').each(function (ind, ele) {
  var selectBoxVal = $(this).closest('div.team').find('select').val();
  selectBoxVal = selectBoxVal!=''? "By "+selectBoxVal:selectBoxVal;
  $('#dispPicks').append($(ele).val() +"  "+selectBoxVal+ '<br/>');
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team">
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Shaks" />
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Hurricanes" />
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Draw" />

<select>
        <option value="">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<br/>
</div>
<div class="team">
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="Crusaders" />
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="Pioneers" />
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="Draw" />
<select>
        <option value="">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<br/>
</div>
<div class="team">
<input type="radio" name="wow" value="Chelsea" />
<input type="radio" name="wow" value="Liverpool" />
<input type="radio" name="wow" value="Draw" />
<select>
        <option value="">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="dispPicks"></div>
```

Comment: some impressive coding skils there buddy thanks for taking the time to do this for me...very much appreciated your solution works spot on!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':radio').change(function (e) {
        //clear the div
        $('#dispPicks').html('');
        //update the div

        if ($(this).val() == "Draw") {
            $(this).siblings("select").val('0');
        }

        $(':radio:checked').each(function (ind, ele) {
            var selectBoxVal = $(this).closest('div.team').find('select').val();
            selectBoxVal = selectBoxVal != '' ? "By " + selectBoxVal : selectBoxVal;
            $('#dispPicks').append($(ele).val() + "  " + selectBoxVal + '<br/>');
        });
    });

    $("select").change(function () {
        //clear the div
        $('#dispPicks').html('');
        //update the div
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            if ($(this).siblings("input[type='radio']:checked").val() != "Draw") {
                $(this).siblings("input[type='radio']").last().prop('checked', true);
            }
        }
        if($(':radio:checked').val()=="Draw"){
            $(this).val('0');
        }
        $(':radio:checked').each(function (ind, ele) {
            var selectBoxVal = $(this).closest('div.team').find('select').val();
            selectBoxVal = selectBoxVal != '' ? "By " + selectBoxVal : selectBoxVal;
            $('#dispPicks').append($(ele).val() + "  " + selectBoxVal + '<br/>');
        });
    });


});
```

[Have a look at the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y0hweumo/2/)

Comment: It is possible to get draw by X in your example. If you change this I will delete my answer and upvote yours.

Comment: @JanJoukeTjalsma Can you explain what you mean by 'get Draw by X' please? I didn't understand that part

Comment: Sorry about that. Should have added it immediatly. If you first click "Draw" (last radio), then use the select to select 6 it shows: Draw by 6. This should not be possible I think. A draw cannot have a difference of 6.

Comment: You are right, its not supposed to do that. I have fixed the code to cater for that as well. Please check :)